# VB6 Crystal Report Code to C# conversion

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, vb6-migration

So I am moving some existing Crystal Reports from VB6 invoked code to C#.

The VB6 Crystal Report engine has a GroupSortFields collection that is set at runtime along with the SortFields collection.

Code looks like this.

```
crystalReportEngine.GroupSortFields(0) = somepassedinstring
crystalReportEngine.SortFields(0) = somepassedinstring
```

Was able to figure out how to set the SortFields in C#, but cant find any documentation to set the GroupSortFields.

Any direction?

UPDATE:
Here is a simplified version of the legacy VB6 code.

```
CR1.ReportFileName = fullPathAndFileNameToRpt
CR1.Connect = dataConnectionString
CR1.ParameterFields(0) = "SortField;" & rptParameter & ";TRUE"
CR1.SelectionFormula = ""{Manager_Category1.List}"="SomeValue""
CR1.GroupSortFields(0) = "Sum({@ABSWeightedValue},{Manager_Category1.Category1})"
CR1.SortFields(0) = "{@ABSWeightedValue}"
CR1.PrinterStartPage = 1
CR1.PrinterStopPage = 1
```

Comment: well in VB for Indexing / arrays they use `()` the equiv in C# would be `[]` also can you show what somepassedinstring looks like.. are you getting any errors.. does the GroupSortFields expect an array[] of string or a string

Comment: There is no GroupSortFields in the .NET Crystal Component.  The issue isnt how to set the array it is where does GroupSortFields map into Crystal.Net

Comment: can you show an example of the data / structure

Comment: What do you have in mind? Database and the formulas created for the report. It is a rather complex report, but the question really isnt about the report it is where did GroupSortFields go in the API? I have many reports to get running in this new process that uses that part of the old API.

Comment: Is GroupSortField in the old code used to Reset the group order dynamically? Also what does 0 mean in that function?

Comment: what's the version of crystal reports that you're moving to?

Comment: Moving to Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0.  The code is in a shared function that is used to create many reports. The code would end up something like this if the strings werent held in variables. crystalReportEngine.SortFields(0) = "{@ABSWeightedValue}" and crystalReportEngine.GroupSortFields(0) = "Sum({@ABSWeightedValue},{Manager_Category1.Category1})". These are old reports that run in a VB6 application that is going away.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `SortFields[i].SortType`?

That can be set to `SortFieldType.GroupSortField` or `SortFieldType.RecordSortField`.

Comment: How would you use these to set the SortFields and GroupSortFields at run time to string values?  For instance the current code resolves to code like this.  crystalReportEngine.SortFields(0) = "{@ABSWeightedValue}" and crystalReportEngine.GroupSortFields(0) = "Sum({@ABSWeightedValue},{Manager_Category1.Category1})"